# Drupal - Relaxed Web Service error

Tags: drupal

Hopefully someone has an answer to my question.
I'm trying to connect to another instance of drupal using deploy and relaxed web services.
However, I keep getting this error
{"message":"The following permissions are required: \u0027restful get relaxed:root\u0027 OR \u0027perform push replication\u0027 OR \u0027perform pull replication\u0027."}

Does anyone have any idea why?
It's a local windows version of drupal (bitnami stack) that i have installed, trying to connect to another drupal version on a linux server.

Can this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

oversight on my part.  There is a replicator role that i forgot to check which solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that passwords are saved correctly in "Config > Web services > Relaxed settings" and for the replicator user role. Check that for both environment (staging and live).
It solved my case.
(If needed, delete the before saved data and create new ones.)